# how to add <link rel="preload" as="font"> in src url of font

Tags: html, css

I just got to know about adding rel='preload' to fonts sources to avoid "flash of invisible text (FOIT)" The thing is I have added the font source with all the minified css in a php file and requiring that php file in code. Like this

```
require_once('styles/common/'.FILENAME_COMMON_CSS);
```

And here is on of the font src.

```
@font-face{font-family:'Open Sans';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(styles/mobile/common/fonts/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OX-hpOqc.woff2) format("woff2");unicode-range:U+0460-052F,U+1C80-1C88,U+20B4,U+2DE0-2DFF,U+A640-A69F,U+FE2E-FE2F}
```

Someone told to add the "preload" part when you are including the css file which contains your code but I am putting the code in php file.
So is there a way I can add rel="preload" in above code? Because I am not using `<link rel="preload" as="font" src='*path*'>`

Comment: The browser receives html and css. It does not know (or care) how it is created on the server. So the part that creates the HTML code has to add the `<link rel="preload" as="font" src='*path*'>` into the the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently there wasn't a way to do it as I was expecting so I found another solution. I added `"font-display: swap;" in @font-face{}.`
The documentation says this feature is not supported by all browsers.